# Phonegap icon system

Tags: android, cordova, icons

I've been working on a Phonegap project (Android and iOS) for 2 months now. Everything works fine and is surprisingly fast once you play around for a while.

Except one thing. I fail to understand how Phonegap handles icons. After a while I have noticed that the "res" folder for my iOS project wasn't being used, instead it was using icons in "platform/ios/projectName/Resource/icons". I've moved all my icons/splash screen in there, linked all of it in my xcode project and everything work fine.

Now I'm struggling with Android, hacking my way in that "drawable" folder of the Android platform folder, failing to understand the role of the config.xml in all of this.

Anyway here are my questions:

1. What is the purpose of the icon references in "www/config.xml" if when it comes to building for a platform, it ignores those paths and actually looks for icon/splash screen elsewhere?
2. What is the purpose of the res folder/subfolder naming, if the build function just blindly copies everything in each platform folder (having blackberry references/png in iOS config/folders).
3. Where should I put the android splash screen image and what's the correct naming? (when i copy the one from "www/res/screen/android" into the "drawable" folder, the build fails for incorrect naming).
4. Basically, what's the Phonegap expected workflow for icons & splashscreens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references listed in config.xml are for Phonegap Build. This link might help:

http://devgirl.org/2013/09/12/phonegap-icons-and-splash-screens-help/